# Are owe and due are the opposites?

Tags: future

"You are due an apology" 
If I say that to someone then it means that I owe them an apology and not the other way around.  I recently debated this with someone and they could not make sense of it and did not agree with me.  If I was owed an apology then I would say "I am due an apology"

Comment: "and not the other way around" -- why?

Answer (score 3):

*Owe* is a ditransitive verb:

> I owe you $5 / an apology.

The more acceptable passivisation is:

> You are owed an apology (by me).

Here, *owed* is the past participle, but it also has the form of a participial adjective.

> You are due an apology (from me)

mirrors this interpretation, with

> due (an apology)
>
> adjective (+ complement).

Comment: +1 Interestingly, using *owe* either the recipient or the giver of the apology can be the subject of the sentence, since both active and passive forms are available. Not so with the adjective *due*. The recipient must be the subject unless you want to go to the *very* passive (and strained) form *An apology is due to you from me.*

Comment: Again interestingly, _due_ is such a strange entity that 'You are due an apology' can mean 'You really deserve an apology' or 'You really deserve an apology and it's time you got it'.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. If I say 'You are due an apology' it means that someone, not necessarily me, owes you an apology.

However, if it were me that owed the apology I think I would say 'I owe you an apology'. 'You are due an apology' seems to be suggesting  that some third party owes the apology. Though I do not rule out that some people might say 'you are due' when it was them who owed the apology.

Comment: Thank you.  I shall demand an apology now from the one who owes me. lol